# Is it still possible to respond directly to a slack event HTTP POST with a message to send?

Tags: python, slack-api

I know when a slack event happens, it comes to you as an HTTP POST (https://api.slack.com/events-api). Is there a way to specify a message to send inside of the response body? I was following this (https://medium.com/@vinodhinic/lessons-i-learnt-while-building-slack-apps-3ecc6c929180) and hoping to be able to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The documentation doesn't indicate that you can, and if you could, the documentation would clearly mention it. Some other APIs for messaging do (Twilio's for instance).

Even if you could, there is a very good reason why you shouldn't that's provided in the Slack documentation:

> Your app should respond to the event request with an HTTP 2xx **within three seconds**. If it does not, we'll consider the event delivery attempt failed. After a failure, we'll retry three times, backing off exponentially.
>
> Maintain a response success rate of at least 5% of events per 60 minutes to prevent automatic disabling.
>
> Respond to events with a HTTP 200 OK as soon as you can. Avoid actually processing and reacting to events within the same process. Implement a queue to handle inbound events after they are received.

If your code is *doing work* (i.e. looking stuff up in a database, or doing some kind of computation, or making a network request) to prepare the response to send back, you run the risk of that work taking too long (blocking) and not having sent back a 200 OK in time, which means your client isn't behaving according to the spec in the documentation. As the documentation recommends, handle the webhook events coming in by putting them on a queue, then send out responses based on what is in the queue.